# How can i remove the loading-animation from a Ext.grid.Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Like the title says, how can i remove the spinwheel from a Panel?

I tried the property "loadMask" or "loadingMask" which seems to work for older versions and also the setLoading() method...

Edit: 'maskOnDisable' also doesn't work by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `setLoading` method to hide the loading mask. For example:

```
gridPanel.setLoading(false,false);
```

You can read the details of this method at [Ext.grid.Panel documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-setLoading). In ExtJS 4, the loading mask is created and displayed by the [Ext.ComponentLoader](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.ComponentLoader).

Comment: Yes already found that function in the api, but it doesnt work for me, whatever i pass to it.

Comment: from where are you calling the method? It should be called before your ComponentLoader start fetching data from server

Comment: Maybe this is the problem, i define a store, then call store.load() and after that i define my Panel and after that i call setLoading(). But i just also tried to load the store after everything else it stays the same.

Comment: Try setting calling the setLoading method from initComponent of your panel. You can also try setting a custom css for the loadingCls through the viewConfig.

Comment: Yes i found the 'loadingCls' already and set it to display none. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

On Extjs4 you can use

viewConfig: {loadMask:false}

I hope this works for you, but if you are using pagination I recommend that you don't hide the mask.

Sam.